# Воспроизведение HTML5 видео на Android

Tags: javascript, android, html5

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
        console.log('Автозагрузка');
        var videoOut = document.getElementById('video');
        videoOut.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
            videoOut.play();
        });
        videoOut.load();
        videoOut.play();
    }
</script>


    <video id="video" width="100%" loop muted onclick="closeVideo()" preload>
        <source src="svideo/svideo1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
        <source src="svideo/svideo1.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
        <source src="svideo/svideo1.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    </video>
```

На Chrome для Android не воспроизводится автоматически.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: Не воспроизводится автоматически.

Comment: Иностранный вариант вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/q/14895616/5441700